# Find maximum size of a 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

I have been asked to create a program in C in which will take an 2d array of eg. 3 numbers and will find the persistance of one number every time by multiplying it until we gat only one number. Then the result of each number will be filed in the second row of the array.

Eg.

For example, the persistence of the number 2736 is 0: first we find that `2 * 7 * 1 * 6 = 252`, then that `2 * 5 * 2 = 20` and finally `2 * 0 = 0` where we come to a single digit. (which in that example is 0).

The numbers for the array will be given from a txt file with the following format:

```
2716 2720
```

so the numbers will be `[2716,2720] : 2176 2177 2178 2179 21720`

The graphical presentaion of every persistance would be

```
Number | Persist
-----------------
  2716  |    3
  2717  |    4
  2718  |    2
  2719  |    3
  2720  |    1
```

and the array after wil be :

```
 array[5][2] = { {2716,3}, {2717,4}, {2718,2}, {2719,3}, {2720,1} };
```

so in the end I need to find the number with the maxinum persistanse (which in my case is 2717) and fprintf it to a txt file called persist.out with the row and the column like this:

```
2717 4
```

My problem is in the last part of copy the array.

Also we need to check if more than one number have the bigger persist and then find the maximum number.

I wrote a code for the last part but isn't very stable and I can't make the check i want.

**UPDATED!**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int multiply_digits(int x)
{
  int z = 1;
  while ( x )
  {
    z *= x % 10;
    x /= 10;
  }

  return z;
}



int main() {

    int a;
    int b;

    FILE *input, *output;

    input = fopen("persist.in","r");
    fscanf(input,"%d %d",&a, &b);
    fclose(input);


    int c = (b - a) + 1;

    int array[c][2];



    array[0][0] = a;

    for(int i = 1; i < c; i++)
    {

        array[i][0] = a + i;

    }



     int i, j;
    for (i=0; i< c; ++i)
    {
        int n = array[i][0];
        int j = 0;
            while (n>9)
            {
            n = multiply_digits(n);
            j++;
            }
        array[i][1] = j;
    }



    for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
       printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

    int indexOfMaximum;
    int maximum = array[0][1];
    for (i = 0 ; i < c ; ++i ) 
    {

      if ( array[i][1] >= maximum ) {
    maximum = array[i][1];
    indexOfMaximum = i;
    }
    } 


}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how can I find the number with the maximum persistance and how to copy the row and the column of it into a txt file

Comment: you must check the result of `fopen`.

Comment: don't worry about it

Answer (score 2):

In your `for` loops, your stop condition is `i <= c` it should be `i < c` since your start index is `0`

Your array is declared `int array[c][2]` so you are reading past the end of the array I assume a garbage value which might in fact be larger than `maximum`, if you want to go up to `c` then declare `int array[1 + c][2]`.

As for the write it into the file part just do

```
fprintf(output, "%d %d\n", array[indexOfMaximum][0], array[indexOfMaximum][1]);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: well maybe your right but my code works my problem is another. Also if i put `i < c` then I miss the last number

Comment: If your code works, it is by accident. And did you fix it and try?

Comment: I mean that you are reading past the array, for the values before that it should be ok, but in your find maximum part, it will cause trouble.

Comment: @GeorgeGkas seriously? for an array declared as dim `[n]`, C allows indexing from `0..(n-1)`. Your program is ill-formed. Whether you choose to believe that is irrelevant; it is still true. The most common ill-conceived conclusion drawn from an ill-formed program is believing that *observed* behavior is *defined* behavior. One is a gamble; one plays by the rules. Your's is the former. Its honestly that simple; belief has nothing to do with it.

Comment: May be, you should initialize `indexOfMaximum` before the `for` loop or it could end up uninitialized, and why don't you test the code to see if it works?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the condition in your last if statement to >= so that you actually get the maximum. With your code if the bigger persist appears multiple times you will only find the first one.

```
if ( array[i][1] >= maximum ) {
    maximum = array[i][1];
    indexOfMaximum = i;
}
```

Comment: checked! But again in that condition how can I make a check to find  in that condition , the bigger number?

Comment: Edited the answer. Just use a variable indexOfMaximum and at the end your 2 values are array[indexOfMaximum][0] and array[indexOfMaximum][1]

Comment: I updated my question but I couldn't understand your answer. Check it please!

Comment: Your array being sorted increasingly, at the end of the for loop the number in array[indexOfMaximum][0] will be the biggest number with the highest persist value. if X has a persist = p and Y > X has a persist also equal to p, then Y is after X in the loop and as p >= p is true indexOfMaximum will become the index of Y. Clearer?